# how to setup a .bat file as windows service?

Tags: window, batch-file

how to setup a .bat file as windows service using command?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Batch files can't be used as windows services.

Comment: @sam - that's not what you asked. Can you please edit your question and clarify _exactly_ what you want to do? And please add details like what language you are writing the windows service in.

Comment: he's probably using python.